# "Cell not executed due to pending input" when using %debug in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using a JupyterLab notebook, with all the latest relevant package versions:

```
ipykernel                    6.17.1
ipython                      8.7.0
ipython-genutils             0.2.0
jupyter                      1.0.0
jupyter-client               7.3.1
jupyter-console              6.4.3
jupyter-core                 4.10.0
jupyter-resource-usage       0.6.1
jupyter-server               1.17.0
jupyterlab                   3.5.0
jupyterlab-pygments          0.2.2
jupyterlab-server            2.1
```

but when I tried to use the magic `%debug` command to inspect what cause an exception in my python code, I get a pop with the message:

```
Cell not executed due to pending input.
The cell has not been executed to avoid kernel deadlock as there is another pending input! 
Submit your pending input and try again.
```

I've found a [closed issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10732) related to this, so I'm guessing there's something wrong with my setup, any hint for investigating this would be very helpful.

EDIT:
I can reproduce the error simply by running the following in a cell (with `%debug` in the next cell below):

```py
a=1
raise ValueError
```

Comment: I assume you mean 'magic `%debug` command' when you wrote 'I tried to use the %magic command to inspect'? Did you try it in JupyterLab? The issue you referenced is for the JupyterLab interface and not the traditional Jupyter notebook interface.

Comment: you're right, I ran the `%debug` command and got that error message. Interestingly, that was in JupyterLab, if I actually try in a Jupyter notebook I can use the `%debug` just fine.

Comment: Hmmm. Sometimes the same issue back in; it's called a regression. If you are able to work around it for now then I'd suggest doing that given JupyterLab development is still at a very fast clip. JupyterLab 4 is in the works and has a lot of differences. The newer debugger in JupyterLab is much more powerful and awesome than the traditional one you are trying to use with %debug. If you haven't tried that I'd encourage looking into it, see [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html). Alternatively, if you can find the issue with %debug is reproducible ...

Comment: <continued> & it seems in the newer pre-releases then maybe a newer issue is in order? Because that is an IPython magic, you also may find a better experience for now, or at least on your current system configuration, trying it in IPython and not JupyterLab? Also because you aren't sharing a 'minimal reproducible example' of code and steps, I'm not clear how to test what you are describing. Or rule out that you are using it conjunction with some complexity that is know to break the feature anyway.

Comment: I've just tried with IPython and there `%debug` works fine. As for the level of complexity, there isn't any, I'll add that to my post. I'll try also the new JupyterLab thanks for the tip

Comment: Darn. Hoping it was complex.

Comment: I see the same behavior you post for two versions I use regularly. (1) Versions 3.4.8 that you get when you press `launch binder` [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) presently, and (2) JupyterLab Version 4.0.0a31 that I am getting via launches from [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/jtpio/d368ab89cee5123ecee60683115e15f3/master?labpath=lab) (just 'Dismiss' the pop-up; it was the quickest solution I found to launch into JupyterLab for now ) (via [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/d368ab89cee5123ecee60683115e15f3).)  ....

Comment: <continued> The problem is I haven't used that magic %debug command myself, and so I don't know if this behavior is new since I don't have an example without it now. I don't know what it should be doing

Comment: it should just...work, so in that example `print(a)` should return 1 etc. To me this looks like enough material to open a bug report

Comment: I recently encountered this problem when upgrading to jupyterlab4. I can only get out by interrupting the kernel.